# Register-ScheduledJob (NOT TASK) to run once at startup

Tags: powershell

I've been pulling my hair out over this.  Is there a way to run a scheduled powershell job (NOT A TASK!!!) to run once at startup.  If I restart the computer a second time, I do not ever want this task to run again.

I already know how to do this with tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you're looking to do isn't directly supported**: In the [`New-JobTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/new-jobtrigger) cmdlet, the `-Once` switch and the `-AtLogon` / `AtStartup` switches cannot be combined.

The **workarounds** are:

- Instead of using a [scheduled job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/about/about_scheduled_jobs), **create an entry in the relevant [`RunOnce` registry key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys)**, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`, with a command line that calls the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)) or - if your scheduled job merely calls an external program, with a call to that program.
- **Create a *self-deleting* scheduled job**; that is, embed code in the job that causes it to delete itself at the end of its invocation.

[This conceptually related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76368440/45375) has answers that demonstrate both techniques for scheduled *tasks*, but it shouldn't be too hard to adapt them to scheduled *jobs*.